# Good list of music suitable for a 45-key clavichord such as ZHI's KOS?

Tags: sheet-music, keyboard

Pretty much the title says it all, but to be more clear....

Is there somewhere a good list of music which can be played on a 45-key clavichord (such as Zuckermann's King of Sweden) 3-and-half-octave with a E-c''' range?

Searching onlines does not yield anything relevant (or I am using utterly wrong search terms). The Boston Clavichord Society does not have anything (perhaps too obvious?) -- The Mutopia Project, The Petrucci and MuseScore libraries either don't have a section for clavichord or even if the do (Petrucci) don't allow to search for and neither show the used range (which would be easy for Mutopia and perhaps MuseScore)

Where do people find music for such an instrument?

PS: somebody with more reputation, please create the clavichord tag and add this question to it.

Comment: Creating new tags is typically a collaborative process triggered by a tag request on meta. If the tag was not considered as urgent up to now, I doubt the proposal is considered. I added the keyboard tag instead, which seems to fit judging from its short description.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a good answer, but what I found is better than the nothing else obtained so far.

Some questionably-looking PDF sheet music retailers have the range for *some* of the piano pieces they offer, for example [this one](https://www.sheetmusicdirect.com/en-US/se/ID_No/15362/Product.aspx) (many other pieces from the same retailer do **not** have the range).

Another retailer (also questionably-looking, but at least with a real-looking team in their [about](https://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/AboutUs.html) page and some connections with the semi-famous [Robert Estrin](https://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/experts/robert/)) appears to have the range for *all* of their piano music, or at least all that I saw, see for example [the same song](https://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/score/JesuPf.html) linked from the business above (note that the arrangement and hence the range is different). This would be "good enough" if they allowed search-by-range or search-by-lowest-note and search-by-highest-note, but sadly they don't. I contacted them asking to add such a possibility.
I was very pleasantly surprised to see that the full [Book I of Preludes and Fugues](https://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/score/PreludeFugueI-1.html) does fit on that small clavichord!!